# std::is_base_of() depth

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a such hierarchy:

```
namespace MyService{
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase(){}

protected:
    IPointer *_somePointer;

};
}
```

```
class IInterface: public MyService::IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IInterface(){}

    virtual std::string get() const = 0;
};
```

```
class ConcreteClass: public IInterface
{
public: 
    std::string get() const
    {
        bool isNull = (_somePointer == NULL);
        return "Hello";
    }
};
```

```
bool isBase = std::is_base_of<IBase, ConcreteClass>::value;
```

I need to check is I3 is derived from I1. But std::is_base_of() doesn't work well for me - it return false.
The goal is to add to any class IBase and check any class is there IBase in it hierarchy

Found the problem, but not solution. My code is:

```
template<class Base, class Derived>
    bool IsDerivedFromBase()
    {
        if( std::tr1::is_fundamental<Base>::value )
            throw MyService::Exceptions::ETypeTraitsInvalidArgument( "Base class can't be POD" );
        if( std::tr1::is_fundamental<Derived>::value )
            throw MyService::Exceptions::ETypeTraitsInvalidArgument( "Derived class can't be POD" );

        bool a = std::tr1::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value;
        return a;
    }
```

and i have a such

```
bool a = std::is_base_of<MyService::IBase, SomeInterface>::value; // true
a = IsDerivedFromBase<MyService::IBase, SomeInterface>(); // false
```

Comment: g++ 4.7.2 behaves as expected: http://ideone.com/8yrx6k

Comment: Clang 4.0 behaves as expected.

Comment: Please, next time, provide a compilable code that reproduces the problem. Just by compiling your code, you'll notice that it's syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Are your types complete?

Comment: Still works after edit: http://ideone.com/XOZHWk

Comment: found problem - added to the queston text

Comment: Still works: http://ideone.com/RfDuPr

Answer (score 4):

This does output `true` with G++ 4.7:

```
class I1{};
class I2: public I1{};
class I3: public I2{};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << std::is_base_of<I1, I3>::value
            << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

<sup>Note that `std::is_base_of<I1, I3>::value` is equivalent to instantiating an object of type `std::is_base_of<I1, I3>` and converting it to `bool`.</sup>

I believe it is accurate in doing so. `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>` is defined as having the condition (§20.9.6):

> `Base` is a base class of `Derived` (10) without regard to cv-qualifiers or `Base` and `Derived` are not unions and name the same class type without regard to cv-qualifiers

*Base class* is defined as so (§10):

> A class `B` is a base class of a class `D` if it is a direct base class of `D` or a direct base class of one of `D`'s base classes.

So yes, `I1` is a base class of `I3` and `std::is_base_of<I1, I3>::value` should be `true`.

Answer (score 2):

[No, the code works:](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7d91ece11402bbade951cf49f211cbda)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C : public B {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "a2b: " << std::is_base_of<A, B>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "b2a: " << std::is_base_of<B, A>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "c2b: " << std::is_base_of<C, B>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "a2c: " << std::is_base_of<A, C>() << '\n';
}
```

yields:

```
a2b: true
b2a: false
c2b: false
a2c: true
```

The above works on GCC 4.6 and 4.7. If you are using something else you need to specify that.

Your error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem.
I had a few .cpp files with unit tests, in which i defined locally classes with the same name.
Didn't find in a standard tis yet, but reproducing code is something like:

```
/// 1.cpp
class IInterface{};
class Interface: public IInterface{};

/// class 2.cpp
class IInterface: public MyService:IBase{};
class Interface: public IInterface{};

/// facility.h
namespace a{ namespace b{
    template<class T, class B>
    bool IsBaseOf(){
        return std::is_base_of<T, B>();
    }
}
}
}

/// ...main
a::b::IsBaseOf<MyService::IBase, Interface>();
```

It should/can fail. But if i make classes names unique it alright.

Comment: This code is invalid, it violates the _One Definition Rule_, class names **must** be unique in the entire program

Comment: It can't _not_ compile it, the errors occur in different files that are compiled separately, that's how C++ works. "My code compiles" is not the same as "my code is correct", that's also how C++ works. The ODR says your program has [tag:undefined-behaviour], that does **not** mean it should fail to compile.